# Request uri too long with webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, webrequest

I want to do a create via a webservice which needs a uri like this:

```
http://<url>/webservice.php?operation=<operation>&elementType=<elementType>&element=<element>&
```

my problem is, element is all information of an email with html body, which is about 6000 characters.
I want to call the url like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(urlToUse.ToString());
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = urlToUse.Length;

var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
var requestStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
requestStreamWriter.Write(urlToUse);
requestStreamWriter.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (responseStream == null) return null;
var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

var responseFromServer = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

responseStreamReader.Close();
responseStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

but it breaks at

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

and says the uri is too long.
I can't change the server's max length of the url and the webservice needs the parameters in the url.
I haven't found a suitable solution for me yet so any help is appreciated.
**Update:**
For anyone facing the same issue, the solution that worked for me was to put my query into an byte-Array like

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = enconding.GetBytes((queryString));
```

and writing that into the webrequest instead of my queryString

```
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: You are using `POST` so why don't you pass the information in body of the request?

Comment: You seem to be confused with how GET and POST work and using a mix of both in your code. If you're sending data via POST, you don't need to include them as query parameters.

Comment: If I add the information to the body, how can I put them after the url so the webservice does what it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put data in the **body** of the request with something a little like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<url>/webservice.php");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new YourObject
    {
        // Pseudo code... Replace <...> with your values etc
        Operation = <YourOperation>,
        ElementType = <YourElementType>,
        Element = <YourElement>,
        // etc...
    });

    HttpResponseMessage response;
    using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
    {
        response = await client.PostAsync("youroperation/", httpContent);
    }

    // Do something with response if you want
}
```

This is JSON based but could be anything you want to pass... This is a simple example that will hopefully give you an idea of how you can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the urlToUse at the question mark:

Something like this (not tested)

```
string[] parts = urlToUse.ToString().Split(new char[]{'?'}, 2);
string url = parts[0];
string data = parts[1];
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
var requestStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
requestStreamWriter.Write(data);
requestStreamWriter.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (responseStream == null) return null;
var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

var responseFromServer = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

responseStreamReader.Close();
responseStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Good luck with your quest.